# Distributed app, password hash

Tags: c#, java, database, oracle, security

We have a distributed app and db table with users.  Their passwords will be stored as hash values.  App consists of win services,winforms, asp and java programs.
One of the Java developers has a function that computes md5 hash for the string (with hardcoded key) and offers to use it everywhere else (which means importing java code to c# and multiplying over the apps that need it).  Is that an ok idea?
What would be your suggestions and what do people usually do in such cases?

P.S. We use Oracle db.

Comment: which version and edition of Oracle (9i Standard, 11g Enterprise, etc)?

Comment: Oracle 9. But I'd like to know if there is a unified way to compute it, so all apps reuse it.

Comment: Don't forget to add salt. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have all the apps pass the password to the DB and have a stored procedure in the db that checks the given password against the stored hash.

There is a standard PL/SQL function for calculating hashes: DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5

You can find a more complete write up of this method here : http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/StoringPasswordsInTheDatabase9i.php

Answer (score 1):

Md5 Doesn't really have a key, as it's a hash not an encryption. Md5 hashing is built in to both java and c#.

What code does any body need to write? It is at most a couple of lines in each implementation language...plus a handful of tests to check that everybody comes up with the same results, capitalisation etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what function he uses (may be not MD5), I only know it computes hash and it's hand written.

Comment: I can't recommend writing (or rather - please please don't write) your own hash function (as in for a password/digest). Use a standard one. And if you use a standard one, use the implementation thats already built in to your language.